# How to set defcustom variable

Tags: emacs, elisp

There is [cperl-mode](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/blob/master/cperl-mode.el)

and the setting I see in source:

```
(defcustom cperl-indent-parens-as-block nil
  "*Non-nil means that non-block ()-, {}- and []-groups are indented as blocks,
but for trailing \",\" inside the group, which won't increase indentation.
One should tune up `cperl-close-paren-offset' as well."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'cperl-indentation-details)
```

I was trying to use `(custom-set-variable '(cperl-indent-parens-as-block t))` but that doesn't work so how can I change this to `t` as global setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function is called `...-variables`:

```
(custom-set-variables '(cperl-indent-parens-as-block t))
```

or you can just use `setq`, since the variable doesn't have a setter defined:

```
(setq cperl-indent-parens-as-block t)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Easiest](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) way to do it is <kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd> <kbd>cperl-indent-parens-as-block</kbd>.

This shows you a nice menu with the possible values etc, and adds the values to your `init.el` (or `emacs.el`) afterwards.